# Прыгает footer при анимации карусели над ним. Подскажите как исправить пожалуйста!

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть вот такая карусель. Центральный элемент карусели увеличивается свойством width:130%.
В этот же момент footer, который сразу под этой каруселью тоже прыгает вверх, потом вниз во время анимации. Как сделать, чтобы footer был статичным?

```html
<div id="target" class="carousel-2 owl-carousel">

  <div class="owl-pic">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="photo">
  </div>

  <div class="owl-pic">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="photo">
  </div>

  <div class="owl-pic">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="photo">
  </div>
</div>


<footer class="social-footer portfolio">
  <div class="icons">
    <div class="social-footer-icons">
      <a href="https://www.vk.com/">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/clouds/100/000000/vk-com.png"/>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/clouds/100/000000/instagram-new--v3.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.t.me/">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/clouds/100/000000/telegram-app.png"/>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставьте минимальный воспроизводимый код. Было бы здорово, если бы вы использовали **фрагмент кода**

Comment: Добавьте ваш код CSS пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте следующее

```
  <style>
    footer
    {
      margin-top: auto
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Дай футеру свойство margin-top: auto;